# How to get Docky to work like gnome-do?

Tags: gnome-do, docky, search

Is there a way to get Docky ton act like Gnome-Do? I installed just the docky package. I would like it to be able to search for other things that are not in the dock. Is this possible or would it just be easier to install Gnome-Do separate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucid's version of Gnome-Do still has the Docky interface available, and it will act like Gnome-Do when you push the keyboard shortcut for Gnome-Do. You shouldn't even need to have Docky installed separately. The version in Maverick removed the Docky interface. (Both are numbered 0.8.3.1 in the about dialog, however.)

Once you have a version of Gnome-Do without Docky removed (see below), the next thing is to run Gnome-Do. If Gnome-Do doesn't pop up when you run it, summon it with <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. Click the downward-pointing triangle on the top right corner of Gnome-Do and click *Preferences*. Click on the *Appearance* tab and select the *Docky* theme in the drop-down at the top of the tab. You can then configure Gnome-Do just as you would configure Docky.

The versions of the `gnome-do` packages after `0.8.3.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1` (`0.8.3.1+dfsg-2` and `0.8.3.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1`) removed the Docky theme. Maverick is also missing the `gnome-do-docklets` package.

You *could* download `gnome-do` and `gnome-do-docklets` from the [Ubuntu Lucid repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gnome-do) (you could probably still install Maverick's version of `gnome-do-plugins` with it). It looks like the only fix you'd miss out on is one for crashes caused by GNOME Keyring. I'm not experienced enough to guarantee this will work right, but I'd do it on my own computer. I have at least checked to ensure there aren't any dependency issues.

A surer, but more difficult, approach, would be to build the latest release of `gnome-do` but reverse the effects of the patch `debian/patches/03_disable_docky.dpatch`.

Comment: No; 0.8.3.1 does not have Docky.

Comment: Looks like it's probably a difference between what's in Maverick and what's in Lucid. I updated my answer and I'll look into it more momentarily.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer again; it now contains information on why the Docky feature is there on 0.8.3.1 in Lucid but missing on 0.8.3.1 in Maverick.

Comment: I found a [blog post](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/10/how-to-install-gnome-do-with-docky-in.html) posted today that advocates the same approach.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I guess I will have to survive having them as separate programs for now. Thanks for the great answers! :)

Comment: unfortunately gnome-do is not stable on my amd64 ubuntu 10.04, and i had to switch back to  docky.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you'll need to install them separately and use them without integration; Docky was split from Do a while ago. The next Do release will likely reintroduce Docky integration.